# Apps for Blackberry users?

Tags: running, app

I have a blackberry 3G 9105, and was wondering whether there are blackberry users here who have any specific recommendations in terms of running apps?

Thanks

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic, please check the [FAQ].

Comment: There is a list of apps in the meta part, see http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/209/3778

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are running outside, Endomondo is a fantastic app. I used to use it for my mountain biking and walking. simply punch in your details, let it locate your position and start running. After finishing your exercise simply click finish and it shows you statistics of the loop you just ran, times over distances at 1 mile intervals. It's also pretty good as it informs you when you have run mile intervals and informs you of the time over that section. It also has a handy built in personal trainer which says encouraging things to you while you exercise.

That's the only one I have ever used, a quick Google result shows quite a few:

Free:

- iMapMyRun
- Adidas miCoach
- runtastic Lite Version: Free
- Greattrainer

Paid:

- Endomondo Pro Version: $3.99
- runtastic Pro Version: $5.99

A search in Blackberry App world should show more results.